# Google App Engine, Maven and Eclipse development setup

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'll try keep this short. I have **Eclipse** with an installed **M2E (Maven to Eclipse)** plugin. I have a **GAE (Google App Engine)** project I'm working on. Everything is working ok apart from one really annoying thing: I have to stop/start the devserver every time I make a change.

If you have any experience with this setup then you might be able to answer this simple question?

I start the development server with "mvn appegnine:devserver" on the command line. Now *I would expect* that if I made changes to a *.jsp for example that those changes would automatically be updated on the devserver. Is this what happens with you?

I have noticed that if I make changes to *.jsp files under my target folder then devserver will see those changes and updates as I would expect. I think my problem lies with Eclipse not copying changes to target folder, but not sure if is even suppose to?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should progress investigating this? I've ran out of ideas :-/

I thank you in advance for any comments you may have.

P.s I know I can run "mvn package" to update files, but this is slow and the devserver runs out of memory after a do it twice.

Answer (score 3):

This can be little painful, depending on how you want to work and which version of eclipse you're using.

1. **Install the m2e-wtp plugin** if you haven't. It's the secret sauce that makes appengine projects work in eclipse. Note this isn't m2e - but another plugin.
2. **Install the GPE** - the google plugin for eclipse if you haven't
3. Make sure your project is being managed by m2e as a maven project.
4. Go into your project properties - enable it as an appengine project using the GPE (listed under 'Google'). Don't forget to tick HRD while you're here.
5. Go to your project build path (Properties -> Java Build Path).

   - Ensure on the source tab that your src/main/resources doesnt have an ** exclusion.
   - Ensure on the libraries tab your have the three libraries 'JDK', 'Google Appengine' and 'Maven Dependencies' and nothing else
   - Ensure on the order and export tab that the appengine dependencies are above the maven dependencies.

It sounds pretty ridiculous - i'm not really sure why its *still* so painful, but that is a good recipe for success. Once that's done, this should allow you to run in debug from eclipse itself, with hotloading of code, jsps, css, scripts etc. I've had this work in helios, indigo and juno.

You can read more about the m2e-wtp setup instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven). They refer to GWT but it's the same for appengine (I'm not sure why the emphasis on using GWT on GAE) because its actually about the correct setup of GPE and Maven.

You will also find that you may need to repeat some parts of step 5 pretty frequently - if your app isn't loading properly take a quick look to ensure that your resources haven't been excluded. This happens when you update your project configuration using the m2e plugin.

The wtp-m2e plugin updates the target folder as resources modified - so this should also resolve your issues running from the command line, but i can't vouch for that - I prefer to run straight out of eclipse.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your comprehensive answer Nick. I’ll give that a go later on today. I was actually using the Google Eclipse plugin and found it really good, but decided to change my Eclipse version and add Maven to the mix because I needed the dependency management.  I’ll let you know how I get on :-)

Comment: Hi Nick, i have tried exactly what u said, but no luck eclipse is throwing error in my face, its really fustrating, following is my error,

**java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectPropertyPage.saveChangesToAppEngineWebXml(GaeProjectPropertyPage.java:890)** in plugin com.google.gdt.eclipse.core

Comment: also, i get another error 

**Description Resource Path Location Type
The App Engine SDK '/Users/Ramesh/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.3/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.3.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location '/Users/Ramesh/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.3/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.3.jar' is not a directory) RameshProfile  Unknown Google App Engine Problem**

what eclipse actually want ?

Comment: Those sorts of errors are pretty frustrating in eclipse. Unfortunately i probably can't help you solve them. My advice regarding the second one is to check your project configuration. Project -> Properties -> Google -> AppEngine and check that you're using a built in SDK. Check 'Configure SDKS'. Next, Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path. On 'Source' make sure you have no exclusions for any source folder. On 'Libraries' you should have NO jar files, just 'Appengine SDK', 'JRE' and 'Maven Dependencies'. On 'Order and Export' ensure the 'Appengine SDK' is ABOVE 'Maven Dependencies'.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you, however I resolved with other way. I use **FileSync** plugin (which can be found in the market place).
With this plugin you configure an *input directory* (webapp) and *output directory* (target).
Any change made to the webapp will be passed to the target.
I have helped too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync like this:

```
     rsync -r --existing   src/main/webapp/ target/ROOT
```

where "ROOT" is the project build finalName.

Answer (score 0):

The below point worked for me.

Ensure on the order and export tab that the appengine dependencies are above the maven dependencies.

Comment: below? There's nothing below your post.  Can you provide a link to which post you are referring to?

Comment: you need to make sure that, on the order and export tab that the appengine dependencies are above the maven dependencies.

Comment: in the eclipse build path setting check that the app engine dependency are above the maven dependency. if not select the app engine dependency and click up in the right side menu